# How can I change my nickname so that it's pronounced correctly?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

My nickname for online games is "Davarius". I'd like the 'var' to be spoken so that it rhymes with 'car'. But people always say it "Da-VARE-ius". Should I spell it different? Or just deal with it.

Comment: You can't win against the internets. I use *facetious* as my nickname, but nobody seems to know how to pronounce this perfectly common English word. It is typically mispronounced by people as *face-TISH-us*, *fass-ITY-us*, or simply *FACE-shus*. -_-

Comment: Whether you _should_ spell it differently is a matter of opinion. If you do want to change the spelling to make sure(r) that people will pronounce it right, you can always just add an extra r: ⟨Davarrius⟩ is at least _less_ likely to be rhymed with _various_.

Comment: I read it as "da-VAH-ree-us" automatically.

Answer (score -2):

Look at how other words are spelled that rhyme with your desired pronunciation. "Serious", "delirious", "imperious".

Comment: Those words would make it sound like Da-Vear-ius, not Da-VAR-ius